# How would I find an apporpriate dopant element for a lattice

Tags: atoms, crystal-structure, metallurgy, atomic-radius

I am trying to figure how would I go about finding a dopant element that would fit in a copper lattice? I already have the data for the atomic dimensions and structure (available below), however how would I find a dopant element that would make it a P-Type material? (Relatively new to chemistry, so bear with me if I ask a stupid question)

Atomic dimensions and structure
Atomic Radius 145 pm 
Covalent Radius 138 pm 
Van der Waals Radius 140 pm 
Crystal Structure Face Centered Cubic 
Lattice Angles 
π/2, π/2, π/2

Lattice Constants 
361.49, 361.49, 361.49 pm

Space Group Name Fm_ 3m 
Space Group Number 225

Comment: Just how do you intend to make Cu, a metal, "p-type"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Copper chalcocite, for example, is a degenerate p-type. To clarify, how would I find a material(s) that would fit within the copper lattice, however a material(s) that leave holes within the valence band.

Comment: Sure, but your example is a compound and not fcc I believe. So, look for other similar transition metal compounds and look at their lattice constants.

Comment: So would Copper and Nickel work? They are both fcc I believe, thus would it still leave a valence hole?